# How to maximise constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, linear-programming, finance

I am not sure how to interpret this problem and where to start to get my values to plot my graphs and get my x, y and etc values as there is too much going on.
Can someone shed some light of how to do this problem?

The problem is:

> You are to help a popular online VOD service maximise their profits by advising the company’s sale team on set ‘sales targets’ for “HD single screen” subscriptions and “SD single screen” subscriptions given that it is 2 times more profitable to sell SD single screen subscriptions than HD single screen ones.
>   It must also be noted that the company must honour its existing HD single screen (5) and SD single screen (10) subscribers.
>   Being an online company profits increase linearly in relation to the number of servers running. In this instance we will only look for the costings of running a single server. That being said, due to hardware limitations, a server can only stream 200 IO streams, where a HD stream consumes 4 IO streams and a SD stream only consumes 1 IO stream.
>   In terms of bandwidth cost, we have a simple contract that provides the first £100 worth (per month) of bandwidth free, after which the cost for bandwidth significantly increases such that users do not exceed this free £100 limit. It is to be noted that on average the bandwidth consumption (per month) of a typical HD subscription never exceeds £1.50 with a similar case for SD subscription being £0.75. 
>   Finally - in addition to the above, it must also be noted that this company is a daughter company from which we lease all our content from our parent company. The costs of the leases are £1 (per month) for HD subscription and £0.75 (per month) for SD subscription. Our aim is not to exceed £80 of leasing cost.

I am not sure if is this how I solve this:

So to rephrase the question: given that $x$ is the number of HD subscriptions sold and $y$ is the number of SD subscriptions sold, maximize $x+2y$, considering the following;
\begin{align}
x≥=5,\;\; & y≥=10 \tag{company honouring contract}\\
4x+y&=200 \tag{IO server streaming}\\
x+0.75y&≤80 \tag{leasing cost}\\
1.5x+0.75y&≤100 \tag{bandwidth}\\
\end{align}

The $5$ HD and $10$ SD existing customers don't really matter and I think they're just there to make sure that the final answer have $x≥5$ and $y≥10$

Am I doing the correct calculations? Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Mathjax in order to make your question more readable. See here for a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The server constraint is an inequality as well. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320904/verify-my-simple-linear-program-formulation/2321124#2321124) how to solve an LP graphically.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865834/linear-programming-optimization-with-multiple-optimal-solutions/2866071#2866071) is another example.

Comment: @callculus can you check my graph below to check if it looks right?

Answer (score 0):

Plotted graph is correct.  $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

[image]

Comment: I don´t know if the graph is right. But note that these are $\leq $-constraints. The solution space is below the lines. What inqualities have you used to obtain the lines?

Comment: @callculus I used:
x+2y
with constraints:

4x+y<=200

1.5x+0.75y<=100

x+0.75y<=80

x.>=5

y>=10

Comment: Now look at the link of the other example below your question. Solve z=x+2y for y and then ...