# Linear Programming: Maximize z = 5x + 4y with Non-Strict Constraint (Graphical Solution)

Tags: linear-programming

Problem:

Maximize z = 5x + 4y

Subject to:

x + 2y >= 24 (Constraint 1)
3x + y <= 6 (Constraint 2)
x + y <= 4 (Constraint 3)
x >= 0 (Non-negativity constraint for x)
y >= 0 (Non-negativity constraint for y)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320904/verify-my-simple-linear-program-formulation/2321124#2321124) is an example, where a LP has been solved graphically.

Comment: First, what have you tried? Second, what do you mean by non-strict constraint?